# Is it possible to have several possible stylesheet paths listed in one XML document?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm going to guess this isn't possible, but I figured I'd ask.

I have a XML stylesheet (XSLT) that I'm using to view XMl files in Word/IE/Chrome. These XML files can be located anywhere on a user's computer, but I'd like to be able to have the XSLT File in the program's Program Files directory. Unfortunately this can now be /Program Files/Test Software/ or /Program Files (x86)/Test Software/. Is it possible to have multiple stylesheet paths in the same XML document?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean "if I include more than one xml-stylesheet processing instruction in my XML document, will it have any effect in a Web browser?"

It's been a while since I ran any tests, but my recollection is that multiple xml-stylesheet instructions work cause no errors in browsers, and that some browsers take the first one listed while others take the last one listed.  And in browsers that support alternate stylesheets, you can use the appropriate pseudo-attributes to get alternate stylesheets listed in the user interface.

So:  "possible", yes, but not with the meaning you appear to want.